# How to move text along with the browser

Tags: layout, browser, html

I'd like to figure out how I can get my text to move along with the browser. Right now my site looks like this: http://simplysweet.shukuya.com/test/. The divs are absolute, but I've tried relative, static, etc... and can't seem to get the text to move along with the image/layout.

Comment: Could you please explain more thoroughly? What would you like to happen and where?

Comment: @user2332349 Please provide some sample code so that the nature of the problem is clear to the visitors. This way it is hard to find what exactly you want to say

Comment: I want this: '<div style="position: fixed; left: 500px; top: 300px; width: 465px">', to move along with my browser... now it's fixed so that it doesn't scroll, but if i dont' have it fixed, it won't stay in the position either =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have your text scroll with the rest of the page you simply need for your divs to be relatively positioned (the default.)

Setting the width of your div to 100% will make it occupy all of the available space in the layout just outside that item, (and so-on up to the root of the document.)

If you want to maintain a "centered" block that is left aligned, use:

margin: auto

on whatever div is just beneath the root of the document.

Comment: I've done this, but now the text won't scroll with the layout. '<div style="position: fixed; left: 500px; top: 300px; width: 465px">
'

Comment: I honestly took a stab in the dark at what you might have wanted based on the wording of your question. You'll need to communicate your requirements more clearly.

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to say is that I would like the text move along with the layout if someone resizes their browser and to also scroll along with the layout/image

Comment: @xKiYoMiNaTiONx I've updated my answer to address your clarifications.

Comment: thank you so much, and with hiding the horizontal scroll, it looks perfect now!! thanks!!

Comment: uh oh, now I got a new problem =(... some of my links in the navigation won't work now... *bangs head on wall*

Comment: @xKiYoMiNaTiONx I'm glad that the css is working for you, I'd appreciate an up vote or an acceptance on my answer. Secondly, can you be a bit more descriptive regarding the latest problem?

Comment: My link codes look like this: '<a href="">x Link x</a>', however, on the actual site, only like the last 8 xLinkx's actually have my hover and a link attached to it. The ones on the top don't work at all!

Answer (score 0):

Use min-width property along with positioning for both div